# Docusign REST API call: Using logical operators for search_text

Tags: filtering, docusignapi, operator-keyword, rest

I’m trying to use a REST API call to find all envelopes with subjects that are either {{cSubject_1}} OR {{cSubject_2}}.
I’m using "search_text" for filtering but I’m not sure how I should use the logical operator for “OR”  for this purpose.
I would appreciate if you could help me with this.
Thanks,
Kathy

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no support for this type of complex query in the search_text for The [Envelopes:listStatusChanges](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/) endpoint.
The search_text allows you to have a single text item that is search across the board (recipients, subject, etc.) and is not limited to a specific meta-data. You can use other filters to filter by other means.
I would recommend storing envelope's meta-data in your application storage (or database) and using your own code to query this information if possible.